# Sequence Behavior for CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Does anybody know of a good sequence (ordered list) behavior for cakePHP 2.x? I used Neil Crookes Seqence Behavior (hosted on GitHub here: https://github.com/neilcrookes/sequence) but this hasn't been updated to 2.x yet.
Thx a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the behavior in 2.x? You'll have to rename the files to CamelCase but after a cursory glance I didn't spot anything particularly 2.x in the code.

Comment: Have to humbly admit I didn't try that yet. Will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just run my Upgrade shell over it. it will autofix 99% of all issues:
https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade

the casing, the filename, the &model to Model $model, ...

Comment: Thx, though in this case all I had to do was to change the name of one file.

Comment: Even better. the rest of the changes are not mandatory but E_STRICT or other small changes (nice to have so to speak).